# PySpark write to parquet extremely slow

Tags: python, pyspark, io

Spark newbie here. I have a fuzzy matching task between a 5000-row sample and a 1.5M-row dataset (~30MB). I'm running on my local machine for now but I have also tried provisioning a GCP cluster for this task.

My spark config looks like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark NLP") \
    .master("local[7]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "16g") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "10") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "7") \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", "300") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.12:3.1.0") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1000M") \
    .getOrCreate().newSession()
```

I have a UDF that takes in a name and runs fuzzy search methods. Then I write into parquet.

```
sample_spark.write.format("parquet") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("compression", "lz4") \
    .option("spark.sql.parquet.write.batchSize", "100") \
    .option("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader", "false") \
    .save("parquet_5k")
```

The UDF takes less than 30s but the writing process takes 3 minutes, and it can become longer if the sample size increase. The actual CPU time is less than 100ms and most of the time is spent in I/O. Is this a normal I/O time to process?

Comment: *"The UDF takes less than 30s..."* - how did you measure the time taken by UDF? with or without an action?

Comment: @samkart it was a `sparkDF.withColumn` to performing the UDF plus the `sparkDF.show()`, so I would say it is with action. I run it on my local machine on VS Code so I was able to see the runtime.